# Сложение 16-ричных чисел

Tags: java

Есть число: `5BFh`

Надо к каждому "символу" прибавить число (например `Eh`) и если результат больше `F`, то "сдвинуть" (отнять 16).

```
5+Eh=20-16=4
Bh+Eh=12+15=30-16=Dh
Fh+Eh=16+15=31-16=Eh
```

Т.е. из `5BFh` должно получиться `4DEh`.
Как это сделать программно на Java?

Comment: Заранее составить массив соответствий и по нему быстренько получить требуемое. `новый_символ = массив(старый_символ, прибавляемое_число)`

Comment: Прибавляемое число каждый раз разное. Большой массив получится. И вопрос скорее для понимания, как это реализовывается учитывая 16ричность?

Comment: вы можете строки перевести в числа, сложить (произвести прочие математические действия) и перевести обратно в строки?

Comment: Да, я так и сделал. Но хочется узнать как это можно по другому сделать.

Comment: А число храниться в переменной какого типа данных? String или int?

Comment: Что то я не понял, как у Вас получается 5+E=4? 5+(E=14) = 19 => 19-16 =3.

Comment: `Прибавляемое число каждый раз разное.` - а я не зря показал ДВУМЕРНЫЙ массив предрасчётных значений... `Большой массив получится.` 256 байт - это большой?